# What does it mean by saying that a number is 'asymptotic to ' another number?

Tags: packing-problem

The following comes from the book *The Geometry of Numbers* by *C.D. Olds, Anneli Lax and Giuliana Davidoff*. After the discussion of the geometry of numbers, its application, lattice-point packing is mentioned.

> Let $K$ be a convex set, or body, symmetrically placed about the
>   origin O.
>
> ...
>
> Now let us consider the density of such a packing in an arbitrary
>   admissible lattice(1), that is, the proportion of space occupyed by
>   the translates of $\frac12 K$. Denote by $V(\frac12 K)$ the volume of
>   each of the translates. **In a large cube of volume $V$, the number of
>   lattice points is asymptotic to $V / \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the volume of the fundamental domain of the admissible lattice under consideration.**

(1) : An admissible lattice for $K$ is a lattice that has no lattice point inside $K$ other than origin.

I am confused with the term 'asymptotic to'. I first came across this term when I learnt curve-sketching in calculus. Let's take a look at a cube in the usual $\mathbb{R}^3$. If I am correct, $\Delta=1$. If I consider a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube with a vertex placed at origin, then $V=27$ and the number of lattice points within the cube or on the boundary would be $64$. Now, what asymptotic property are we looking at?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should consider $V$ as a varying value, and consider how the number of points evolves as $V$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @bof : You are right! Thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One says that two quantities/functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, depending on a prameter $t$, are asymptotically equal (as $t \to \infty$) when the limit of $f(t)/g(t)$ is $1$.

Considering larger and larger cubes you will see that the quotient of the two quantities you consider will tend to one. (The absolute difference might grow however; this is not a contradiction.)

Comment: Thanks for replying! Could you also explain this to me? 'If $K$ is a set with at least one admissible lattice, we take $\Delta (K)=\inf \Delta (L)$ where the infimum is taken over all admissible lattices for $K$.' I don't understand what it is talking about!

Comment: A lattice is admissible for $K$ if there is not lattice point (other than $0$) in $K$. To give an example: if you consider the lattice of all integer points, then this lattice is not admissible for $K$ a disk of radius $3/2$ since this contains  $(1,0)$  for instance. Yet if you consider the lattice of all even integers than it is admissible as the disc does not contain any point with even integral coordinates, other than $(0,0)$. Among all lattices that are admissible for some $K$ you try to find which is the smalles possible $\Delta$ of the lattice and this is the $\Delta (K)$.

Comment: That's very detail! Thx a lot!